# mongodb one to many relation

Tags: mongodb, one-to-many, mongo-c-driver

I am new to MongoDB moving in from traditional SQL relational approach. I am working on a simple “Category has many Products” scenario (c#.Net). Where Category has

```
List<Product>
```

My questions are.

1. Question 1: On Add Product screen I have a drop down for Categories. So on Submit should I 
   First **Insert** Product in Products Collection and then
   **Push**  this Product in Nested Product of Categories collection.

   _categoryCollection.Update(id, Update< Category>.Push…)
2. Question 2: 
   Or 
   We shouldn’t just have anything called “Product Collection”. Instead we should have only one Categories collection with Nested Products in it. And on submit just Push this new Product in respective Category.

   Question 2.1 : What if we want to do this association for product with category after the product is added. ?
3. Or
   Question 3: 
   Considering question one. Should we have CategoryId in Product entity  ? does this makes any sense in No SQL concepts ?

Answer (score 0):

I've always found this MongoDB article a good resource for such questions.

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/product-catalog/

The questions you need to ask are, how will the data be accessed? What are my objects and how are they formed? Start with your programming first, create your classes (domain objects) and your access patterns, then worry about Mongo. You'll see, Mongo won't really get in your way. That is what is was meant to do.

So, going back to your scenario. If you know the categories are going to be big in number, need to be tightly controlled and manipulated often, then you could have a second collection for them and reference back to that collection's _id field in your category field in the product documents. Important is, the values themselves for the categories should be stored with each product document, in order to have fast reads due to one less query or the need to join the data.

Scott

Comment: i got your point 
but if i want to keep separate documents. is it a two step process when ever i insert in Products i.e.
 I First Insert Product in Products Collection and then Push this Product in Nested Product of Categories collection?

Comment: I'd say, you should have a product collection with a category attribute. If you want all products of one category, you query the product collection. You'll need an index on the categories. One collection, one query. If you need to update the product, it is one query. If you need to update a category, it is two queries, but doesn't happen often so ok.

Comment: but in my application i want users to add categories and later select category while adding products.

Answer (score 0):

A few considerations can be made here:

```
If a category has many products but a product cannot belong to more than one category, then
    If number of products is not expected to be very large per category, then
        Nest products inside category document
    Else, use a different collection for products and use field 'categoryId' in them
Else, use use a different collection for products and use field 'categoryId' in them
```

Nest documents only when they have one definite parent and they are not huge or too many. Otherwise, the parent document will get huge with no way to control its size.

Comment: i got your point 
but if i want to keep separate documents. is it a two step process when ever i insert in Products i.e.
 I First Insert Product in Products Collection and then Push this Product in Nested Product of Categories collection?

Comment: If you are maintaining two collections, there will be no question of nesting. So you push a product in its collection with the categoryId field populated. You can then use this field to "join" those collections.